# How to distribute light equally on a surface?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, rendering

I have the following setup:
[image]

The black rectangle is my light source, the gray panel is the rendered panel.
How can I distribute the light in an equal mode on the panel?

I'm using Cycles in Blender 2.79

Comment: If you want your gray panel to be evenly lit, I think you should make it an emission material and remove all the lights from the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a sun lamp pointing directly downwards, and set a non-glossy material for your wooden plane, e.g. a simple diffuse one:
[image: setup]

Answer (score 1):

You could also increase the size of the lamp such that it is much larger than the gray panel